# NuGet Build Failure In Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I've got NuGet 2.1.31002.9028 installed in Visual studio 2012. When I enable package restore and add any package (like EntityFramework) to my project, I get the following error when building the project:

```
Error   1   The system cannot find the path specified.  ConsoleApplication1
Error   2   The command ""D:\Code\ConsoleApplication1\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "D:\Code\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "D:\Code\ConsoleApplication1\ "" exited with code -1.    ConsoleApplication1
Warning 3   The referenced component 'System' could not be found.   ConsoleApplication1
```

There's a warning like the one above for every reference.
The command in the second error works fine when I run it from a command prompt. I have "Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build" checked and I also tried adding   a EnableNuGetPackageRestore environment variable, none of which fixed the problem. I also don't get this problem on my other machine, which makes it even more confusing.

I appreciate any help on this, and am more than happy to provide any additional info if needed.

Comment: Nuget related issues are being tracked at http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic. Search or open issue there to get quick answer

Comment: Change MSBuild project build output verbosity from Minimal to Diagnostics in Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Build and Run, and then you can see what is the detailed error message instead of -1.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to **allow NuGet to download missing packages during build**:

[image]

I had the same issue, so it should help.

source: http://blog.nuget.org/20120518/package-restore-and-consent.html

Comment: We had this this issue and ticking this box fixed the problem.  Clearly something was missing and we probably could also have fixed it by updating the packages prior to the build.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one, here are few things I would have tried

1. Create a console app and see if it repros? (without nuget package installation)
2. Is system correctly referenced in references? May be try removing and adding it back.
3. Does it repro for other project types, like class library?

Hope it helps.

Comment: The same happens for every type of project. It builds fine without package restore, but as soon as I add that it breaks.

Comment: Also, running  Update-Package -Reinstall fixes the references, but the build errors stay.

Comment: Is it possible you could share your project and I can give it a try on my PC.

Comment: Project runs fine on my other machine. Reinstallin VS12 or NuGet didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I see your -source is blank. On the machine where it repros can you check if there is atleast one package source selected? It can be checked  from tools->option->package manager->package sources.

Comment: can you please share the project which is showing this problem. You can upload the zip to http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2914 which also shows similar symptoms.